# Adding columns from multiple files to the new file with column name = file name on Linux

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, sed

I have multiple files having .profile extension with 6 columns. The first 3 columns of each file is same. I want to have the output file containing the first 3 (similar) columns and then appending the sixth column from each file. The name of the columns being appended to the output file should be the same as the input file. The input file looks like this

```
 FID       IID  PHENO    CNT   CNT2    SCORE
  00010   0001002      2     12      2 -0.00285
  00017   0001702      2     12      2 -0.00285
```

Another input file looks like this

```
FID       IID  PHENO    CNT   CNT2    SCORE
  00010   0001002      2     28      9 -0.00843036
  00017   0001702      2     28      9 0.00710286
```

The names of the two files are "Artery_Aorta.ENSG00000000460.12.wgt.RDat.txt.profile" and "Artery_Aorta.ENSG00000000971.11.wgt.RDat.txt.profile" respectively. I want my output file to look like

```
FID       IID  PHENO  ENSG00000000460.12  ENSG00000000971.11
  00010   0001002    2   -0.00285   -0.00843036
  00017   0001702    2   -0.00285     0.00710286
```

Till now I have tried

```
paste *.profile | awk '{print $1, $2, $3, $6, $6 + 6}'
```

But the output is not as desired. It is adding 6 to the values in $6. However I wanted to print each sixth column appended with the previous columns in the output file. The output file looks like this

```
FID IID PHENO SCORE 6
00010 0001002 2 -0.00843036 5.99157
00017 0001702 2 0.00710286 6.0071
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 1):

AWK solution if You need added 6th column from each input file and sorted as Your input:

```
awk '
(NR==FNR) { arro[++order]=$1 FS $2 FS $3; arr[$1 FS $2 FS $3]=$6; }
(NR!=FNR) { arr[$1 FS $2 FS $3]=arr[$1 FS $2 FS $3] FS $6; }
END { for (i=1;i<=order;i++) print(arro[i] FS arr[arro[i]]); }
' *.profile
```

Output:

```
FID IID PHENO SCORE SCORE
00010 0001002 2 -0.00285 -0.00843036
00017 0001702 2 -0.00285 0.00710286
```

Input:

```
$ ls *.profile
Artery_Aorta.ENSG00000000460.12.wgt.RDat.txt.profile  Artery_Aorta.ENSG00000000971.11.wgt.RDat.txt.profile
```

Per comment request here is solution with replacing added column with filename substring:

```
awk '
(FNR==1) {match(FILENAME,/ENSG[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/); $6=substr(FILENAME,RSTART,RLENGTH);}
(NR==FNR) { arro[++order]=$1 FS $2 FS $3; arr[$1 FS $2 FS $3]=$6; }
(NR!=FNR) { arr[$1 FS $2 FS $3]=arr[$1 FS $2 FS $3] FS $6; }
END { for (i=1;i<=order;i++) print(arro[i] FS arr[arro[i]]); }
' *.profile
```

Output:

```
FID IID PHENO ENSG00000000460.12 ENSG00000000971.11
00010 0001002 2 -0.00285 -0.00843036
00017 0001702 2 -0.00285 0.00710286
```

Comment: Thank you. This is working but I needed the part of the name of the file starting with ENSG followed by the number (for example, ENSG00000000460.12) as the column name in the output file :( Can you please explain the code a bit if possible?

Comment: I added renamed columns solution into my answer. Explanation on first file (NR==FNR) I am creating associative array with index per columns 1,2,3 and assigning to it value of column 6. Every other file (NR!=FNR) additionally there is added column 6 as next column and so on. In the end array is printed per order to keep same order as in input.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your input files are tab delimited and don't have these leading spaces in front of the first column, the following script generates your expected output:

```
#! /bin/bash
merge() {
    cols=$(seq -s, 6 6 $(("$#" * 6)))
    header=$(grep -o 'ENSG[0-9]*.[0-9]*' <<< "$*" | paste -s)
    paste "$@" | cut -f1-3,"$cols" | sed "1s/SCORE.*/$header/"
}
merge Artery_Aorta.*
```